# Django version in GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine

In the Google App Engine [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django), it is said that we can use different versions of Django:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library 
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

So do we really need to download any other (>0.96) Django versions and to put them in the application directory, or any other place, because only Django 0.96 is included with the App Engine SDK? Also, do we need to remove them before uploading the project to the server?

Can someone describe this process?

Comment: I'm interested in this question, and also what is considered "best practice" at this point.

Comment: Are you using app-engine-patch or Django-nonrel?

Answer (score 1):

Django 0.96, 1.0.2, and 1.1 are available on AppEngine, but only 0.96 comes with the AppEngine SDK download. You can still use 1.0.2 or 1.1, you just need to download and install it separately. You don't need to put it in your app directory; when you upload to the AppEngine environment it will pick up the copy they have.

Comment: I've installed  Django 1.1(by default it was installed in my Python25\Lib\site-packages folder) after that I receive errors when I tried to run my application

Comment: what errors? make sure django is in your python path. you might doublecheck by launching the python interpreter and doing something like 'import django.db'